# Visual Studio 2015 custom code analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2015, static-code-analysis

I've been trying to test using custom code analysis rules for a database project in visual studio 2015 and have not been able to get it to work. I build the dll file and copy it in to the \Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions directory but instead of the new rule showing up in the code analysis the project fails to load. Is an enterprise edition of VS2015 required to use custom code rules?

The walkthrough I was using is here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632175(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Just to confirm: You did restart VS after copying dll?

Comment: Yup, restart VS after copying the dll.